# Update row value only once when multiple results returned in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I need to run an UPDATE script with a value returned from a CASE WHEN statement. The condition used might lead to have the same order (table ORDER) affetcted by different erorrs. 

As example, order.id = 20 can be affected by Error 1 and Error 2, but I need to update it only once with the value Error 1 (the order in the CASE WHEN shows the priority).
 The goal would be to have only Error 1 to be set in the field STATUS. Is this possible to be achieved in TSQL? Or should I better implement the logic with a console application?
Thanks.

```
UPDATE O
SET STATUS = (  
CASE
    WHEN E.EXPID = 'E1' THEN 'Error1' 
    WHEN E.EXPID = 'E3' THEN 'Error2'
    WHEN E.EXPID = 'E2' THEN 'Error3'
    ELSE 'EX'
END )
FROM ORDER O 
INNER JOIN EXCP E ON O.ID = E.ORDERID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a CTE to grab the top "error" and `join` that result to your order table.

```
;WITH TopError 
AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY ExpID ASC) AS ROWID, *
    FROM Excp
)

SELECT * 
-- UPDATE O SET STATUS = CASE WHEN T.EXPID = 'E1' THEN 'Error1' WHEN T.EXPID = 'E2' THEN 'Error2' WHEN T.EXPID = 'E3' THEN 'Error3' ELSE 'EX' END
FROM TopError T
JOIN Order O
  ON T.ORDERID = O.ID
WHERE T.ROWID=1
```

Try it as a `SELECT`, if you're satisfied with the results, switch to an `UPDATE`.

Comment: The query building the CTE "TopError" returns me the whole Excp rows with all ROWID set to "1". Therefore when I execute the select afterwards I get the same results as in my orignal query, since all the CTE rows has ROWID = 1. In the statement SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ExpID ASC) AS ROWID, the field ID is my Excp.ID column.

Comment: Sorry the CTE should be partitioned by `ORDERID` not `ID`. Updated.

Comment: Initially I used OrderID, but when I run the query it complains about that field saying it is not a valid column. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are right it was a typo on my side. It works like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, cheers.  You might also move the case into the CTE and then add `AND ISNULL(O.STATUS,'') <> T.NEWSTATUS` to avoid updating a row with the same value as before.

Comment: In case the order of EXPID would not be already sorted (I edited my question, where the order is givne by priority), how could be possible to update the status only once and with the most important error first?

Comment: Just alter this line `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY ExpID ASC) AS ROWID`.  Change this `ORDER BY ExpID ASC` to the required order.  Based on your comments it would be something like `ORDER BY Priority DESC` (assuming 1 is is low priority, 10 is high).

Comment: Thanks JiggsJedi for the comment. The priority that I have to follow is given by the exact order of the error type (ie. E1, E3, E2) since there is a semantic behind them. Therefore I can't sort over them since I should follow that specific order.

Comment: What I originally put in my answer is `ORDER BY ExpID ASC` -- this would sort them based on content.  E1>E2>E3.  This should work unless you have others that don't fit that pattern.

Comment: I edited my question specifying that the priority is not given by the Error number (as E2 more priority than E3), rather than their position in the CASE, that is E3 has more priority than E2 and should be updated instead of this in case both interest the same order. But I do not know if this is possible with TSQL, therefore I start thinking to develop a little console application to make the data migration.

Comment: I completely glazed over that, sorry -- try this  `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ExpID='E1' THEN 1 WHEN ExpID='E3' THEN 2 WHEN ExpID='E2' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END ASC`